# Distinguished point example for Pollard rho for ECDLP solving

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have implemented the [Serial Pollard Rho Algorithm for solving Elliptic curve discrete log problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2u11.png) . Now I am try to parallelize it using the [Parallel Pollard Rho Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqwAF.png).

so I just need some help to understand what kind property I can use for selecting distinguished points for collision detection. It would be a great help if some examples can be suggested also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *any* property. The thing to get right is the probability for some point to be a distinguished point. For example if we want one distinguished* point per 2^32 points, we could define a distinguished point as a point which has all last `x` 32 bits 0.

For example in Sage with point `P`:

```
>>> P.xy()[0].lift() & 0xffffffff == 0
True/False
```

In the normal case, this will do, but I admit that this is not really ideal when you are calculating elliptic curve arithmetic in a projective or Jacobian coordinate system, because you will have to do an inversion for every distinguished-point-test.